# What is the polite way to tell taxi driver that he can stop here?

Tags: modal-verbs, politeness

**My question is I want to primarily give the driver a choice. The secondary consideration is not being rude.**

I take taxi to home. My home is in a community. I often tell taxi driver "You can stop here." when the taxi is at the gate of my community. In this way, the taxi remains on the big street, he doesn't have to drive into my community and make many turns.

If I say "Can you stop here?", it seems I am requesting him to stop here. I'm of cause happy if he want to drive to the front of my house. And my community has some exits. Who knows if one exit is convenient for the taxi's next destination.

I just want to tell him that he can stop at the gate. He can drive to the front of my house if he want.

Many of [my friends](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/236068/can-i-use-you-can-rather-than-could-you-in-restaurants) tell me "You can" means I'm a master, he is my slave, I'm giving permission to him to stop here. That is not what I want.

What is the polite way to tell taxi driver that he can stop here?

Comment: Is this in the USA? By community are you referring to a closed estate, a village? A cordoned off area, can you be more specific?

Comment: You don't have to give the taxi driver your actual address; just say you are going to the entrance to your community. The driver will likely *prefer* to take you to your door, if only because it will increase the fare. But in the end, the driver takes you where you tell them to take you.

Comment: Exist...did you mean "exit"? *Who knows if one exist is convenient for the taxi's next destination.*

Answer (score 26):

There are many options to choose from.  Here are a few that are polite.

> "You can stop off here, if you like; I can easily walk to my apartment
>   from this corner."

Another option is:

> "My home is inside this community, but to save you needing to drive
>   through you are welcome to drop me off here."

Your friend is not correct is saying that the "can" connotes a master/slave relationship, as it all depends on other matters - e.g. your tone of voice, how friendly you have been during the journey, etc.

Regardless, by adding "if you like" you give the driver the option.

Better still, give the driver notice a block or two earlier, by saying something like: "I live in the XYZ community at 123 Smith St.  You're welcome to drive through or drop me off at the gate."  The driver then makes his/her own choice.

Comment: +1 "if you like"

Comment: Agreed regarding "can".  It's entirely contextual.  Telling a waiter, for example, "you can leave now" would certainly have the potential to sound rude and dismissive.  But an explicit statement which shows regard for their preferences-- "if you like", "if it's convenient", etc-- takes away the possibility of seeming short or rude.

Comment: Thinking that "can" sounds like master/slave is foreign to me.  Can implies (weakly) that there is a choice.  A master would say "You will stop the car right here", or "Stop the car now".  But maybe I'm a harsh master...

Comment: @JPhi1618 I think it depends on whether 'implying a choice' is appropriate in the given situation. _"You can stop here if you want"_ is fine, because you are giving the driver an option he doesn't automatically have. _"You can leave now"_ (to a waiter) is rude because you are implying that the waiter needs your permission to leave, which he doesn't.

Answer (score 14):

[A similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/236068/can-i-use-you-can-rather-than-could-you-in-restaurants) came up recently but in a restaurant setting. If you say:

> You can get me the bill now.

that's rude because you are telling the waiter what to do. It's the same as saying:

> **Go and** get me the bill now.
>
> **Fetch** me the bill now.

The waiter knows beforehand that the bill is required at the end of the meal. The only thing you're saying is that you want the bill now, not later. The request is not time sensitive. If you get the bill five minutes later there will be no major consequences.

Telling a taxi driver:

> You can stop here.

is not rude because it's giving the taxi driver information that they don't already have. The taxi driver doesn't know beforehand that here is a good place for you. The request is time sensitive. If you tell the taxi driver even thirty seconds later you will have missed the right place to set you down.

You can't really change the sentence except by saying:

> **Stop** here please.

Make sure you add "please" to soften the request!

There are many other ways of saying this politely, too many to list them all here. Some are:

> Would you let me out here?
>
> This is fine right here.
>
> I can walk from here.
>
> You don't need to go all the way up the driveway.
>
> This will do.
>
> It's just by that tree there.

... and so on. Anything that lets the taxi driver know the journey is at its end.

What makes "You can" rude is the word "now", whether it's spoken or just implied. "You can stop here **now**" would also be rude since adding "now" has changed the sentence from giving information into a command. "Would you let me out **now** please?" is also rude despite the politeness indicators "would" and "please". "Now" is ruder than "would" and "please" in combination since it has turned a request into a command.

To leave it up to the taxi driver whether to stop or not, make it explicit that you're giving them a choice:

> You don't need to go all the way up the driveway **if you don't want to**.
>
> You can drop me off here instead of driving all the way up **if you want to**.
>
> **Either** here **or at the door** is fine.

etc.

Comment: `that's rude because you are telling the waiter what to do` - why this? It's literally the job of the waiter to be told what to do (same for other servants or subordinates).

Comment: @Haukinger because a server is not a servant.

Comment: @Haukinger the answers to the question linked in the question here explains why it's rude.

Comment: I'm unclear whether you're saying that the situation is the same as the waiter, and that "You can ..." is as equally rude to the taxi driver and to the waiter, or if you're contrasting with the waiter example, and saying that the taxi driver situation is different because of the new information aspect.

Comment: This OP asked the restaurant question. We are being led around by the nose, I'm afraid. These things are easily found online.

Comment: @Lambie Yet you didn't find a reference and post it here. I think the question itself is valid. OP is told "You can X" is always rude. I answer "It's not **always** rude, context matters."

Comment: I don't think this answers the question that was asked. My understanding of the question is that the asker is wondering how to say this so that it is *not* interpreted as a request, but rather as actually giving the driver the choice of either stopping or not stopping.

Comment: @TannerSwett "You don't need to go all the way up the driveway." is definitely not a request, it is giving the driver an option. In the context of the other question and "Many of my friends tell me 'You can' means I'm a master, he is my slave", I think the OP is asking about rudeness, not necessarily about giving options.

Comment: To me, "You don't need to go all the way up the driveway" sounds like a request which is phrased as a statement of permission for the sake of politeness. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: @TannerSwett That's the whole point of the OP's question. How to phrase a request so that it is polite. Some sentences will be explicit requests, others implicit requests disguised as choices (or statements of permission if you like). You can't leave it all up the to taxi driver! "My destination is unimportant. Sydney, Perth, you choose! It's all the same to me!" They're performing a service for you that does have a few uncertainties, so it is reasonable to have input as long as it's polite.

Comment: @CJDennis I think my question is how to say a non-request and avoid it being interpreted as rude.

Comment: @Gqqnbig Can you clarify if you want to simply **avoid rudeness**, or if you want to **give the driver a choice** whether to stop right now or keep going to your front door?

Comment: @CJDennis Main goal is give the driver a choice. But I can't give choice in a rude way.

Comment: It's an **excellent point** that the restaurant phrasing is **different from** the tax phrasing.  English is whacky; it's just how it is.

Comment: I don't think it's rude to ask a server for the check when you want it. Otherwise you may have to wait 30 minutes or longer to get it if the server is busy. Customers have a right (I think) to end their meal when they want to, within reason. Of course no reason to be rude about it ("bring me my check now!"), but done politely I don't see any issue ("could you bring the check?"). Maybe the issue was with the word "now"?

Comment: I would question the difference made at the start of this answer though: the server doesn't know the diner wants the bill *now*, just that they'll want it *sometime*. "Sometime" could be 30 minutes or even an hour from now if the restaurant is busy or the diner is in a hurry.

Comment: @bob Practically every native speaker (including me) who has answered here has said it's rude and given a reason why. Note the exact wording being described as rude: "You can X". That's not giving the waiter a choice, it's giving them a command.

Comment: @CJDennis I don't disagree with you. I do think this answer could be edited just a tiny bit to make it more correct: it's not rude to let the waiter know you need the check now, it's rude to word the request as a demand. The waiter doesn't by default know *when* you need the check. The answer includes the fact that the waiter knows you'll need the check at some point as part of the rationale that it's rude to request it "now", and I argue that this isn't accurate. It would be rude to ask with polite wording to get the check "now" multiple times tho because *then* the waiter does already know.

Comment: (And for what it's worth, I'm a native speaker too. :)).

Comment: @bob Sorry for the implication that you weren't a native speaker. I get annoyed when people do that to me too! The difference is you're not _asking_ the waiter to get you the bill now, you're _telling_ the waiter to get you the bill now. Yes, you can use tone of voice to change the default message, but it's easier to use a phrase that already has the correct default tone of voice.

Comment: @CJDennis No worries! :)  I agree.

Answer (score 11):

The standard sentence (at least in the UK) is:

> Anywhere here is fine, thanks.

No need to overcomplicate it.

Comment: Short and to the point.

Comment: Almost word for word my usual go-to choice, also a UK resident.

Answer (score 7):

It's polite to say "you can" if you're letting someone know it's okay by you to do something that may be more convenient for them. You should only use it if you're fine with them choosing *not* to do that thing. It's rude to say "you can" when you're asking someone to do something for you.

This means it's fine in your example. The driver can drop you at the gate if he likes, or he can drive you to your front door if he prefers. I've personally said something similar to lots of drivers. They sometimes say okay and stop, and sometimes they insist on driving me all the way. I'm fine with them choosing either option, as you seem to be. Telling them about their options is perfectly polite, but you should make it clear that you're okay with them choosing to drive you all the way instead. "You can drop me at the gate instead of driving the whole way, if you prefer" is better than "you can drop me here, please", because the latter sounds like you're requesting for them to drop you there rather than giving them an option.

A counter example is if you asked the taxi driver to drive you home and then changed your mind halfway there and decided you'd rather go to your friend's house. If in that case you said "actually, you can drop me at my friend's house instead at [address]", that would be very rude. The difference is you are *asking them to do something for you*, which they may or may not actually want to do. To be clear, it's absolutely fine to ask a taxi driver to change their destination, but you need to form it as a request which they have the agency to accept or decline, rather than tell them they "can" do it.

Another example that's in a restaurant setting, since that was your original question. Say you are seated at a table with more chairs than intended, and for some reason you don't want the chairs there. Telling them "you can take these extra chairs away" would be incredibly rude, because you have no reason to think they have any desire to do that. However, if you saw them trying to scrounge up chairs for a large party, it would be very kind for you to call them over and say "you can take these extra chairs". Again, the difference is whether you are requesting something you want versus letting them know you're okay with them doing something that will be helpful to them.

A simple test is to ask yourself, "if they chose not to do this thing, would I be upset?" If the answer is "yes", then you are making a request, and you should phrase it with "can you" or something similar instead. If the answer is "no, I'm fine with it either way, it's completely their choice", then it's okay to say "you can", although you should make sure it's clear that's the case.

Comment: Your third paragraph is really not right. One can change one's mind during a cab ride and say: "If in that case you said "actually, you can drop me at my friend's house instead at [address]", that would be very rude." **That is simply not true**. A cab driver is all about being asked to do something, and sometimes "can you" can be the same as "you can" with the word please. Again, the use of the word please is crucial.

Comment: @Lambie I don't think its a good idea to rely on someone to understand "can you"/'you can" distinction exactly the same as you have at a particular moment. I would not use "you can..." phrase when I need to know what choice will be made/possible. "Can you ..." clearly indicates that I expect an answer while "you can …" give them choice that not necessary need to be confirmed. Indeed driver will probably try to clarify which option you actually need but with "you can..." they don't have to.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You can stop here or down the road a bit, please. = Can you stop here or down the road a bit, please? Choice: either one means the same thing, and I suspect this has zero to do with English.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on tone of voice:

"You can stop here." is fine if your tone of voice is nice.

Also, it is the same thing as: "Can you stop here".

It's as simple as that.

**But, it is always a good idea to say please.**

Your friends are wrong. "You can" does not mean your are the master.

Your tone of voice is what makes a difference in cases such as these.

POLITE
"Would you please stop here?" [or please at the end]
"Can you please stop here?" [or please at the end]
"Please stop here."

This use of can in English is very, very common.

"Can you bring me a glass of water, please?"

Comment: "Please stop here" (please first) makes it sound like the driver already knows you want to stop but has decided to keep driving. "Please stop here." "No!" "Please!" I'd say "Stop here please" instead (please last).

Comment: @CJDennis Again, it depends on your **tone of voice**.

Comment: I also notice you've swapped "you" and "can" in most of your examples. That makes a big difference. "Can you bring me a glass of water?" is polite. "You can bring me a glass of water." out of the blue is rude by default unless you make a huge effort with your tone of voice, you have established good rapport with the waiter, or you are responding to their question "How **can** I help you?".

Comment: "you can stop here" is utterly different in many ways from "can you stop here"

Comment: @Fattie No, it isn't when said the right way and with **please**. If  you ask to go to a particular block in a city and have not specified a building number, the cab moves along the block and you can say "You can stop here please" which would be exactly the same thing as "Please stop here".

Comment: often adding "please" sounds almost sarcastic. it's a very difficult issue. the first line of the answer is totally correct.

Comment: @Fattie That's ridiculous, frankly. In a context where a service is being rendered, "please" is considered de rigueur.

Comment: I'm afraid not.  With a cliché gruff NY taxi driver, you'd probably utter:  "What about .. here .. good one."  Or  "Right there is good .. great." If you said to the driver (for some reason) "could you pass me a tissue" that would certainly be *please*.  But the navigation of just where to stop is a "normal part of the communication structure".

Comment: @Fattie Most NY cab drivers these days don't even know English very well.

Comment: heh that's absolutely true.

Comment: @Lambie “you can...” and “can you...” mean different things, aside from the politeness. One is a suggestion, the other a request

Comment: @Lambie all acceptable, polite answers. I go for “anywhere here’s great, thanks”. My point was not that any were unacceptable. They have different meanings.

Comment: @Lambie yes. You said “...which would be exactly the same thing as...”. That, to me, makes me think you consider them to be exactly the same. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Tim In terms of politeness.

Comment: @Lambie So it's alright for you to be slightly imprecise but everyone else has to say what they mean exactly?

Comment: @CJDennis I was addressing TIm, **not you**.  I have made my position clear with regard to cab drivers. Please stop hounding me,.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are all fine, but in the specific case of taxi ride, I'll offer a slightly different opinion about the social aspect of it:

"Stop Here" or "Stop here, please" is fine, especially if both of you are speaking English as a second language.

Clarity and brevity are important, especially since time is a factor.  Your demeanor when you speak communicates more about your feelings than the actual words, in any case.  If you use too many words the important part of the message that you need to communicate is obscured by the pleasantries.

Comment: "Stop here" is rude without the please. This is really very simple...

Comment: @Lambie No, as you say " it depends on your **tone of voice**".

Comment: @CJDennis Regardless, it would be rude as an imperative like that. The tone of voice applies to: Stop here please.

Comment: @Lambie You've said exactly the same thing in your answer and criticised this answer for being wrong. "'You can stop here.' is fine if your tone of voice is nice." Your words. There's no difference with "Stop here".

Comment: @CJDennis No, I did not. I said it for: You **can stop** here. I did not say: Stop here. Anywhere.

Comment: @Lambie Don't be so literal. Your message is that tone of voice can determine whether your message is rude or polite. I can make "Stop here" very polite with just my tone of voice. "Stop here." is polite. "Stop here!" is rude.

Comment: this answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: @CJDennis You keep trying to "get me" but you won't. **Please stop trying**.

Comment: Case in point, of it still being rude even if you say please.

Comment: "especially if" - neither of you speak to each other the entire time. *Driver nods. Driver drives me. I pay driver. Driver nods.* = 5 stars.

Answer (score 0):

I like being more direct.

"Please let me out at the gate."
Or, "Please let me out at this intersection."

Thank you.

Comment: Good answer. Even more polite if "Please" is exchanged with "Could you".

Comment: @bob I would consider "Would you please let me out at the gate?"  Would conveys a willingness, and an option, where as could conveys capability.  Might you agree, @bob?

Comment: That one is tricky. In the U.S. at least "would you" can be a loaded phrase that can convey passive-agressiveness. But that may vary by region.

Comment: Well, I am not tuned into the passive aggressive regional tendencies.  I normally say something like, "Kindly stop at the gate, and I would like to get out there."  However when giving general advise, I tend to go direct, since it has less likelihood of being mis-presented or misconstrued.  In any event, the comments should help to educate and confuse the OP. I notice visitors from Argentina and many parts of Europe are apologetically polite when they ask for something like a drop off point.  I tend to interpret things in the best possible light, but a cantankerous  cabbie may not.

Answer (score 0):

After so many years in the US, I finally get the meaning of the English word "can". Blame my primary school teacher.

My Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, which is used to be my go-to reference, has meaning "[used to make suggestions](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/can1?q=can)".

Nevertheless, this meaning is uncommon in other dictionaries.

[Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/can_v1) has

> II.iii.17.
> Expressing an inclination in a conditional form. Chiefly in the first person, or in narrative implying first-person use.

The point is an "if" clause, and the first-person "I".

So I'm better to say "**I** can get off here **if** you like".

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/can has

> Sense 1. used to express possibility
>
> Sense 2. sometimes used to tell someone angrily to do something
>
> Sense 3. to be allowed to

While sometimes "can" is used to express possibility, listeners may interpret it as sense 2. I guess that's why hordes of people on this site get pissed off when I ask servers "you can give me the check".

"may" or "might" don't work either. Oxford English Dictionary has

> II.iv.21.b. Expressing a possibility that contrasts with a person's actual behaviour.
>
> II.iv.21.b.i. might with infinitive, used to convey a counsel or suggestion of action, or a complaint that some action is neglected.

If the driver has passed the gate, then I can say "You might drop me off at the gate."

In conclusion, "I can" and "something can" are safe.
Rephrase "you can". If you can't, say "you can xxx **if you like**", or add "please".